# How can I retrieve a specific cell value from another Excel sheet using this complex logic that find the row using another value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am absolutly new in Excell and I have the following doubt about how to implement this behavior.

I am in a specific cell of a sheet and I have to retrieve the value of a specific cell of another sheet named **CurrenciesInfo**.

I know that I can do something like this:

```
=CurrenciesInfo!P7
```

The problem is that I know the column in my **CurrenciesInfo** folder but I don't know the exact row. But I can retrieve it.

Basically I know that the 3th column of my **CurrenciesInfo** sheet contains an univoque value that can be used to find the exact row.

So for example a single row of my **CurrenciesInfo** sheet have the 3th field having **BTC** as value.

What I want to do is, in the other sheet, instead use this simple formula:

```
=CurrenciesInfo!P7
```

create a more complex formula that perform the following query:

> "Into the **CurrenciesInfo** sheet retrieve the value of the 7th
>   column of the row which have the 3th column value equal to **BTC**"

How can I implement something like this?

Comment: @pnuts Is it possible that my Excel does'nt contain the VLOOKUP() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your excel sheet is in english, this may be functional:

=INDIRECT("CurrenciesInfo!"&ADDRESS(MATCH("BTC";CurrenciesInfo!C:C;0);7))

But if you sheet is in another language, try to convert it in google.

Comment: Much better to use VLOOKUP as per pnuts suggestion...or INDEX/MATCH either of those will be simpler, shorter, more efficient and more robust